# Need javascript code for button press and hold

Tags: javascript, mouse

I'd like a short smallest possible javascript routine that when a mousedown occurs on a button it first responds just like a mouseclick and then if the user keeps the button pressed it responds as if the user was continously sending mouseclicks and after a while with the button held down acts as if the user was accelerating their mouseclicks...basically think of it like a keypress repeat with acceleration in time.
i.e. user holds down mouse button  (x=call function) - x___x___x___x__x__x_x_x_x_xxxxxxx

Answer (score 23, accepted):

```
function holdit(btn, action, start, speedup) {
    var t;

    var repeat = function () {
        action();
        t = setTimeout(repeat, start);
        start = start / speedup;
    }

    btn.mousedown = function() {
        repeat();
    }

    btn.mouseup = function () {
        clearTimeout(t);
    }
};

/* to use */
holdit(btn, function () { }, 1000, 2); /* x..1000ms..x..500ms..x..250ms..x */
```

Comment: thanks. i added a log function for the exponential curve rather than the linear but thats almost exactly what i was looking for.

Comment: I needed to clear the timeout on mouseout as well, otherwise I could slide the mouse away from the button and then the scrolling would keep on going.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but it looks like you've got some semicolons out of place, the internal function declarations need semicolons and the outer function declaration does not.

Comment: This worked well for me but I had to replace "mouseup" etc. with "onmouseup" etc. And I also had to add this to avoid a nasty bug by bailing, like this: `onmouseout = onmouseup;`

Answer (score 4):

When the button is pressed, call `window.setTimeout` with your intended time and the function `x`, and set the timer again at the end of `x` but this time with a smaller interval.

Clear the timeout using `window.clearTimeout` upon release of the mouse button.

Comment: I was busy trying to write the code for him, but decided not to and in the mean time you posted this and it was exactly what I was working on. Very nice.

Answer (score 2):

Just put the below toggleOn in the OnMouseDown and toggleOff in the OnMouseUp of the button.

```
var tid = 0;
var speed = 100;

function toggleOn(){
    if(tid==0){
        tid=setInterval('ThingToDo()',speed);
    }
}
function toggleOff(){
    if(tid!=0){
        clearInterval(tid);
        tid=0;
    }
}
function ThingToDo{

}
```

Comment: This is a simple solution that works, but it uses global variables. I also prefer other solutions where each iteration calls the next one, both for safer logic and because then each call can change the interval length (for acceleration).

Answer (score 0):

I just release a jQuery plugin, check this [demo](https://phuong.github.io/jqueryClickAndHold/) on this [repo](https://github.com/phuong/jqueryClickAndHold).

```
$('button').clickAndHold(function (e, n) {
    console.log("Call me baby ", n);
});
```

Comment: It would be great if it handles also button pressed with keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

@glenuular: Thanks for this interesting approach!
There were some small problems with it: 
- The start value was not reset, so on the second use it started too fast.
- The start value was divided without limit, so it became very small after short time.
- Arguments were not passed to the called method. (Now limited to 6 args, usually sufficient to pass 'ev').

```
    function holdit( btn, method, start, speedup ) {
    var t, keep = start;
    var repeat = function () {
        var args = Array.prototype.slice.call( arguments );
        method.apply( this, args );
        t = setTimeout( repeat, start, args[0], args[1], args[2], args[3], args[4], args[5] );
        if ( start > keep / 20 ) start = start / speedup;
    }
    btn.onmousedown = btn.mousedown = repeat;
    //
    btn.onmouseout = btn.mouseout = btn.onmouseup = btn.mouseup = function () {
        clearTimeout( t );
        start = keep;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I upgraded neouser99 solution because i ran into some problems with it ^^

```
let holdIt = (btn, action, start, speedup, limit) => {
    let t;
    let startValue = start;

    let repeat = () => {
        action();
        t = setTimeout(repeat, startValue);
        (startValue > limit) ? startValue /= speedup: startValue = limit;
    }

    btn.onmousedown = () => {
        repeat();
    }

    const stopActionEvents = ['mouseup', 'mouseout'];

    stopActionEvents.forEach(event => {
        btn.addEventListener(event, () => {
            clearTimeout(t);
            startValue = start;
        })
    });

};

holdIt(actionButton, functionToDo, 500, 2, 5);
```

Answer (score -1):

something like the psuedo code below might work..

```
var isClicked = false;
var clickCounter = 100;
function fnTrackClick(){
   if(isClicked){
      clickCounter--;
      setTimeout(clickCounter * 100, fnTrackClick);
   }
}

<input type="button" value="blah" onmousedown="isClicked=true;" onmouseover="fnTrackClick();" onmouseup="isClicked = false;" />
```