# Trigger a function multiple time according to button press long time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Suppose there is  -

```
<script>
    function move() {...}
</script>
<input type="button" value="move">
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/urielz/2n4f9/)

How could I trigger the `move()` according to the long time press on `<input type="button" value="move">` ?

For example -

A press of 1 second would call `move()` 50 times , 2 second press would call it 100 times ,  and so on .

A script which measure the press long time could be found [here](http://jsfiddle.net/urielz/pZ6FR/)  .

A solution using jQuery would be acceptable too .

Comment: Instead of using `click` event, start your action on mouse down and then keep doing it until mouse up.

Comment: Possible duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/79816/need-javascript-code-for-button-press-and-hold

Comment: you can measure the time between `mousedown` and `mouseup` and decide how long your animation would be according to the result of your calculations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code :)

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var longpress = false;
    var interv;

    function move()
    {
        console.log("move");    
    }

    $("button").on('click', function () {
        (longpress) ? alert("Long Press") : alert("Short Press");
    });

    var startTime, endTime;
    $("button").on('mousedown', function () {
        startTime = new Date().getTime();
        interv = setInterval(function(){
            move();
        }, 100);
    });

    $("button").on('mouseup', function () {
        endTime = new Date().getTime();
        longpress = (endTime - startTime < 500) ? false : true;
        clearInterval(interv);
    });

});
```

DEMO : http://jsfiddle.net/pZ6FR/1/

Comment: I strongly suggest that you add explanation of what your code is doing to your answer - and expand it to actually do what the OP is asking.

Comment: @AleksG it's simple you can start an interval on mousedown event and stop it on mouseup, "move" function will be called n times :)

Answer (score 0):

Check this solution :

```
function holdit(btn, action, start, speedup) {
    var t;

    var repeat = function () {
        action();
        t = setTimeout(repeat, start);
        start = start / speedup;
    }

    btn.mousedown = function() {
        repeat();
    }

    btn.mouseup = function () {
        clearTimeout(t);
    }
};

/* to use */
holdit(btn, function () { }, 1000, 2); /* x..1000ms..x..500ms..x..250ms..x */
```

Taken from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79816/need-javascript-code-for-button-press-and-hold) Stackoverflow question

Answer (score 0):

I would pass the move() function a variable that contains the number of iterations you want to perform. Then, have the move() function call itself recursively until `var iterations` is 0.

I would see it looking like this:

```
<script>
function move(iterations){
  //do actions
  //...
  //check if move() should run again
  if(iterations > 0){
    move(iterations-1);
  }
}
```

Now, your pressTime() function just needs to call move() with the desired iterations. Hope this helps.