# When does a click become a hold?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, dom-events

I'm making a web app where a button's behavior is different if the user clicks vs holds the button. I have been experimenting with different timings and it got me wondering if there is any established standard for this kind of thing.

For clarification: I am wondering if there is an exact timing that is standard. Below is the code I am using with 150ms being the threshold for a hold.

```
function onMouseDown()
{
    var holdTimeout = setTimeout(function()
    {
        //Hold code (also cancels click event)
    }, 150);

    var cancelHold = function()
    {
        clearTimeout(holdTimeout);
    };
    window.onmouseup = cancelHold;
}

function onClick()
{
    //Click code
}
```

Comment: don't know any standards for that. You need to evaluate how long the element have been clicked on. go check [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79816/need-javascript-code-for-button-press-and-hold)

Comment: Mobile devices that use touch-and-hold allow the user to adjust the timing.  Worth researching as your use seems similar.

Answer (score 0):

Answering exactly your question, hold becomes click. You could set the `click` event (it's release in fact), inside the `mousedown` event. Run the code below and try holding and release the mouse button.

```js
document.getElementById("click").addEventListener('mousedown', (e) => {
  var i = 0;
  var int = setInterval(() => {
    console.log("hold " + i++);//<-- actions when we hold the button
  }, 200)

  document.getElementById("click").addEventListener("click", () => {

    clearInterval(int);

    console.log("release")//<-- actions when we release the button

  })

});
```

```html
<div id="click">click</div>
```

In this case, if we hold the button **less that 200 milliseconds**, just the `click` (release) event is fired.