# How do I change my js click button to hold down

Tags: javascript, jquery, mousedown

Here is my button code

```
$("#btn_Shiftup,#menufavs_btn_Shiftup").click(function () {             
    user_favourites_add('.group_button_2','#menufavs_btn_Shiftup','Shiftup()');    
});
```

Comment: This question doesn't really give us anything to help you with, as it currently stands.  Please read **[ask]** and then modify the question so we can help :)

Comment: Welcome to SO, :) Didn't get the question exactly. You can provide little more explanation what exactly you want to achieve.  Also what `user_favourites_add` function does.

Comment: so sorry! i just noticed my other text was removed when adding the code, I would like my code to work as a mouse held down function! so while mouse it clicked i want the button to keep running until i leave the mouse oh and the user_favourites_add is just a bookmark of the button, so that is kinda like to save the button to a favorite menu

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand probably you need `mousedown` event see this https://stackoverflow.com/a/51935522/6121568

Comment: ok I am explaining in a very horrible way because I am not a coder lol, ok so my id of the button is #btn_Shiftup, and the jsx function is Shiftup(), how do I make this function run repeatedly until i leave the mouse button

Comment: if you re *not a coder* please consider if this is the right place for you to ask. While people may be very willing to help you, the general goal should always be to teach you, not to do something for you. So please reconsider if you want to learn, or just want something done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use jQuery `mousedown()` Method.

The `mousedown` event occurs when the left mouse button is pressed down over the selected element.
The `mousedown()` method triggers the `mousedown event`, or attaches a function to run when a `mousedown` event occurs.

> Tip: This method is often used together with the `mouseup()` method.

```
$("#btn_Shiftup,#menufavs_btn_Shiftup").mousedown(function(){
    // Do your things here 
});
```

Example and detailed information you can find [here](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/event_mousedown.asp)

```js
var timer = null;
var subject = $("#subject")[0];

var shifter =  function() {
  var newShifterPosition =  subject.style.top ? subject.style.top.split("px")[0] : "100";
  newShifterPosition =  parseInt(newShifterPosition) - 2;
  newShifterPosition = newShifterPosition < 10 ? 100 : newShifterPosition;
  subject.style.top = newShifterPosition + "px";
}


var shiftUp = function() {
   timer = setInterval(function(){
      shifter();    
   }, 200); 
}

var stopShifting = function() {
  timer && clearInterval(timer);
  timer = null;
  $(document).off('mouseup')
}


$(".btn_shiftup").mousedown(function(){
    shiftUp();
    // Stop execution of code when ever a mouse up event happens
    $(document).mouseup(function(){
        stopShifting();
    });

});
```

```css
.container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  background: #ffeeff;
}

#subject {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  background: #ff000f;
  top: 100px;
  left: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>




<div class="container"> 
  <button class="btn_shiftup">Shift Up</button>
  <span id="subject"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: so I changed it to mousedown and it still runs as normal, does nothing while its held down

Comment: how do I use it together? Im really sorry for the silly questions

Comment: @NaeemArendse Mousedown is a single event, so it fires only once. You could use a function with a setInterval() call that activates on mousedown and deactivates on mouseup.

Comment: that sounds like what I need yes but I have no clue how to do that, Im not a coder, my dev is too busy at the moment so I am trying to change the button myself

Comment: Added an example to show how it works, when you hold start button code will continue executing, and once you release it will stop.

Comment: this is what i need my button to do but where do I put my id and function() https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51934069/when-does-a-click-become-a-hold/51935522#51935522

Comment: @Piccaza Maybe using the click event instead of mouseup would be better. If you press down and move your mouse off the button and release, it doesn't activate the mouseup event, and doesn't respond to that event anymore.

Comment: yes what you did above works well, but i cant find where to put #btn_Shiftup and Shiftup()

Comment: `#btn_Shiftup` this is your button ID, so instead of `$(".start")` you can use `$("#btn_Shiftup")`

Comment: `Shiftup()` looks like a function call, which needed to be called when user holding the `#btn_Shiftup` button. You can call that funciton in `updateTime` function instead of `output.innerHTML = new Date()`

Comment: here is what i have now var timer = null;
        var output = $("#output")[0];
        var updateTime = function() {
        timer = setInterval(function(){
        output.innerHTML = new Date()
        }, 1000); 
        }
        var stopTimer = function() {
        clearInterval(timer);
        }
        $("#btn_Shiftup").mousedown(function(){
        updateTime();
        });
        $("#btn_Shiftup").mouseup(function(){
        stopTimer();
        });

Comment: @NaeemArendse updated the example with similar function name you have used.

Comment: `$("#btn_Shiftup").mouseup` shoudl be `$(document).mouseup`

Comment: ok so what you did there was perfect, but you created a square and container, and made functions to shift it up, so the function i have that is called Shiftup() already does this, so it confused me lol, i basically need this function to keep firing Shiftup() as long as mouse is held down

Comment: i feel sorry for you who has to deal with me, lol im really dumb with these type of things

Comment: if you can show me how my (ID, Class, Function)#btn_Shiftup, .group_button_2 , Shiftup() fits in the code you gave then that would be awesome

Comment: @NaeemArendse I think it's better to communicate directly to resolve your scenario and implement it properly, rather than shooting in the dark here. You can ping me directly in my email (dipakchandranp15@gmail.com), happy to resolve and code it for you.  Thank you.