# How to click and hold down the button for a certain second with javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to make a button that if a guest button number 1, then button number 2 will be clicked and then pressed down for about 3 seconds, is it possible using jQuery?

I already tried using the `mousedown()` and `click()` but it doesnt press it down, only click. and already tried to googled it but doesnt found the solution

**EDIT:**

Here is the js file, it's a simple js that only need to be clicked and then pressed down for 3 seconds.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.turbo').on('click', function() {
    document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'Turbo clicked';

    $('.accelerate').click(function() {
        alert('accelerate clicked & pressed for 3 seconds');
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: share your code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to detect a long press on a div in Jquery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14586883/how-to-detect-a-long-press-on-a-div-in-jquery)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Need javascript code for button press and hold](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79816/need-javascript-code-for-button-press-and-hold)

Comment: @LelioFaieta edited

Comment: @oel it's not even the same what am i asking about :)

Comment: @Wimanicesir it's not what am i looking for

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code below

```
var pressedDown = false,
clickedBtn = false;
$('button.btn1').click(function(){
    clickedBtn = true;
    $btn1 = $(this);
    $btn1.prop('disabled', true);
    setTimeout(function(){
        $btn1.prop('disabled', false);
    }, 10000);
})

$('button.btn2').on('mousedown', function(e){
    if(clickedBtn){
        pressedDown = true;
        setTimeout(function(){
            if(pressedDown){
                //run code here
            }
        }, 3000);
    }
}).on('mouseup', function(e){
    pressedDown = false;
})
```

Comment: the user didn't need to pressed down a button and hold it, it just need a single click and then hold the other button for 3 seconds

Comment: okay... you want the user to click the first button once and then hold down the second button for 3 seconds?

Comment: yes, the second button will be hold down using jquery, so user only clicked the first button only. after he/she clicked the first button, first button will be disabled for 10 seconds, meanwhile the second button will hold down by jquery which is will give an extra boost for the speed, after 3 second, the user need to hold down the second button by himself but with a normal speed, (not the boosted speed)

Comment: okay... i have editted my answer. and i believe thats your goal