# Execute jquery event when the button is pressed (Hold click)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following increment / decriment buttons. I want to fire the event when the button is pressed and not only when clicked.

Notice that when you click the button once and hold enter, it does what i want to achive, but it should be done with click.

```js
  var Basket = {
     plusIncrementButton : $("#plus-btn"),
     minusIncrementButton : $("#minus-btn"),
     quantityInput : $('#qty_input')
  };

  
  /* Increment button */
  Basket.plusIncrementButton.on('click',e=>{
    Basket.quantityInput.val(parseInt(Basket.quantityInput.val()) + 1 );
        });
    Basket.minusIncrementButton.on('click',e=>{
        Basket.quantityInput.val(parseInt(Basket.quantityInput.val()) - 1 );
    if (Basket.quantityInput.val() == 0) {
        Basket.quantityInput.val(1);
    }

        });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="input-group mb-3">
<div class="input-group-prepend">
 <button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm incbtn" id="minus-btn">decrement</button>
                             </div>
<input type="number" id="qty_input" class="form-control form-control-sm" value="1" min="1">
                             <div class="input-group-prepend">
<button class="btn btn-success btn-sm incbtn" id="plus-btn">Increment</button>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: So you surely should look into mousedown and mouseup events?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Need javascript code for button press and hold](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79816/need-javascript-code-for-button-press-and-hold)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be done by using recursive. I'm using `speed` to adjust the speed while incrementing. I'm also adding `mouseleave` to prevent the function to keep looping this function when the cursor leave the button. You can do the opposite for decrementing.

EDIT: To get this running on mobile devices, just add `touchstart`, `touchend`, and `touchmove` into the code.

```js
var timeout;
var speed = 500;

// Increment button
$('#plus-btn').on('mousedown mouseup mouseleave', e => {
  if (e.type == "mousedown") {
    increment(speed);
  } else {
    stop()
  }
});

// Increment function
function increment(speed) {
  $('#qty-input').val(parseInt($('#qty-input').val()) + 1);
  timeout = setTimeout(() => {
    increment(speed * 0.8);
  }, speed);
}

function stop() {
  clearTimeout(timeout);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="input-group-prepend">
  <button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm incbtn" id="minus-btn">decrement</button>
</div>
<input type="number" id="qty-input" class="form-control form-control-sm" value="1" min="1">
<div class="input-group-prepend">
  <button class="btn btn-success btn-sm incbtn" id="plus-btn">Increment</button>
</div>
```

Comment: note that mousedown event doesn't fire on tablet / mobile